# Laravel Voyager Mutator

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I'm having some issues using [Voyager](https://voyager.devdojo.com/). I can create Accessors to attributes, as described in the [documentation](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/bread-accessors). It works nicely to access the data, but I also have to create a Mutator to change the data before saving it. Apparently, there's no implementation by Voyager, so I tried to do it through [Laravel way](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators). It also works very nicely in common environments, but for some reason, there is a **different behavior** with Voyager.

The **Mutator** is called after the **Accessor**, even when only browsing:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Company extends Model
{
  
  public function setNameAttribute($value){ // my mutator
      $value = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", '', $value);
      $this->attributes['name'] = $value;
  }
  public function getNameBrowseAttribute(){ // my accessor
      return $this->name . '...'; // example 
  }

}
```

**What is happening:**

When I access the browser of my Model, the `getNameBrowseAttribute` is called, as it should be, but after that, the `setNameAttribute` is called as well, which should not happen because I'm browsing, and not saving or updating the Model.

I tried to debug the code, and the last Voyager file called is a view, from `voyager/storage/framework/views/`, where `$data` is the Model:

```
if ($data->{$row->field.'_browse'}) {
   $data->{$row->field} = $data->{$row->field.'_browse'}; // <-- this line
}
```

As you can see, it is calling a method with `...browse`, and not `set...`

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do with model events. Use the saving event.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events